# C# Split() in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, split

### listBox2 contents:

0:FirstProduct
1:ProductAgain
2:AnotherProduct
3:OkFinalProduct

What I'm trying to do, when the selected index has changed on listBox2, is to have it make my int "DBID" the value of the number before the ":".

Here's my attempt:

```
    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }
    int DBID;
    DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(":"[0]));
    ShowProduct(DBID);
}
```

ANY help with this is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks guys

**EDIT -** 
Sorry, yes I actually tried:

```
DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(':')[0]);
```

but im getting the following errors:

- The best overloaded method match for string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

  Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]

**EDIT #2 -**
When using:

```
DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(':')[0]);
```

After running the application and clicking on a different listbox item, I'm encountering this exception:

NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I appreciate all the help so far guys!

Comment: By `":"[0]` did you mean `':'`?

Comment: He probably means `.Split(":")[0]`

Comment: Sorry, yes I actually tried:

DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(':')[0]);

but im getting the following errors:

The best overloaded method match for string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments.
Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Comment: You would only see that error if you are using quotation marks instead of apostrophes.  I just ran a test and it works perfectly using the code in my answer.

Comment: interesting, I retyped it and no errors! however, when I actually run the application and click on a different value, I encounter this exception: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object      :(     I greatly appreciate the help so far guys!

Comment: It could be an error related to something else that occurs on postback.  You should probably open a new question and post all of your codep-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safer way will be to replace the single statement with the following code,

```
if (listBox3.SelectedValue != null)
{
    string selectedValue = listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(selectedValue.Split(':')[0], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out DBID))
        {
            // Process DBID
        }
        else
        {
            // Cannot convert to Int32
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `breakpoints` in the code, to find where the `NullReferenceException` is occurring.

**Note** that this example assumes that you are using `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox` or `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox`, and not `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox`. In the later case, the `SelectedValue` is a `string` and not an `object` (as pointed out by @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy in another answer's comment)

Answer (score 4):

Try changing:

```
DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(":"[0]));
```

To:

```
DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(':')[0]);
```

**Update**

Try this instead.  It explicitly adds a new char:

```
DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(new char[] { ':' })[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DBID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedValue.ToString().Split(':')[0]);
```

Comment: SelectedValue itself is a string

Comment: Are you sure that the `SelectedValue` is a string? Isn't it an `object`?

Comment: @Devendra It returns a string in webapps and object in winforms, my answer is half-correct.And OP didn't mention which he is using.

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy, thanks for the information. Did not know that. :)